# Regex to match multiple different lines

Tags: regex

I have the following file below and I would like to have a some regex expressions that could parse the file and give me an output like

139.162.78.135:41448 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

139.162.78.135:41448 Connection reset, restarting

TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET]139.162.78.135:41448

139.162.78.135:41448 Fatal TLS Error

139.162.78.135:41448 VERIFY ERROR

139.162.78.135:41448 Bad encapsulated packet length

Note: this is for a program called fail2ban so that I can easily ban these ips that are trying to intrude my server.

I tried to parse the connection reset line like this `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+ Connection reset, restarting` But I don't know how to form another expression that can match the rest in one go.

```
Jun 19 04:27:29 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 139.162.78.135:41448 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Jun 19 04:27:29 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 139.162.78.135:41448 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 04:27:29 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]139.162.78.135:41828
Jun 19 04:27:29 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 139.162.78.135:41828 WARNING: Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (18245), which must be > 0 and <= 1627 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is equal on both peers -- this condition could also indicate a possible active attack on the TCP link -- [Attempting restart...]
Jun 19 04:27:29 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 139.162.78.135:41828 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Jun 19 04:27:29 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 139.162.78.135:41828 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 04:52:47 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]67.52.172.103:2577
Jun 19 04:52:47 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 67.52.172.103:2577 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Jun 19 04:52:47 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 67.52.172.103:2577 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 04:52:48 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]67.52.172.103:63975
Jun 19 04:52:48 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 67.52.172.103:63975 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Jun 19 04:52:48 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 67.52.172.103:63975 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 04:56:52 Server ovpn-openvpn_udp[811]: TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]185.200.118.55:55292
Jun 19 09:17:44 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]154.16.133.10:13456
Jun 19 09:17:44 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 154.16.133.10:13456 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Jun 19 09:17:44 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 154.16.133.10:13456 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 09:17:44 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]154.16.133.10:13769
Jun 19 09:17:59 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 154.16.133.10:13769 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
Jun 19 09:17:59 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 154.16.133.10:13769 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 09:19:25 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]184.105.139.70:50240
Jun 19 09:19:26 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 184.105.139.70:50240 WARNING: Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (5635), which must be > 0 and <= 1627 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is equal on both peers -- this condition could also indicate a possible active attack on the TCP link -- [Attempting restart...]
Jun 19 09:19:26 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 184.105.139.70:50240 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Jun 19 09:19:26 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 184.105.139.70:50240 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 14:11:58 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]223.146.71.5:59970
Jun 19 14:11:58 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 223.146.71.5:59970 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Jun 19 14:11:58 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 223.146.71.5:59970 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 14:11:59 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]223.146.71.5:60145
Jun 19 14:11:59 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 223.146.71.5:60145 WARNING: Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (21331), which must be > 0 and <= 1627 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is equal on both peers -- this condition could also indicate a possible active attack on the TCP link -- [Attempting restart...]
Jun 19 14:11:59 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 223.146.71.5:60145 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Jun 19 14:11:59 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 223.146.71.5:60145 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 14:25:16 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]112.113.195.89:3079
Jun 19 14:26:16 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 112.113.195.89:3079 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Jun 19 14:26:16 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 112.113.195.89:3079 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Jun 19 14:26:16 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 112.113.195.89:3079 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Jun 19 14:26:17 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 112.113.195.89:3079 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 16:27:19 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]213.202.230.144:2616
Jun 19 16:28:19 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 213.202.230.144:2616 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Jun 19 16:28:19 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 213.202.230.144:2616 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Jun 19 16:28:19 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 213.202.230.144:2616 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Jun 19 16:28:19 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 213.202.230.144:2616 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Jun 19 16:59:10 Server ovpn-openvpn_udp[811]: TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]185.200.118.41:40431
Jun 19 19:00:17 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]178.73.215.171:23509
Jun 19 19:00:17 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 178.73.215.171:23509 WARNING: Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (5635), which must be > 0 and <= 1627 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is equal on both peers -- this condition could also indicate a possible active attack on the TCP link -- [Attempting restart...]
Jun 19 19:00:17 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 178.73.215.171:23509 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Jun 19 19:00:17 Server ovpn-openvpn_tcp[856]: 178.73.215.171:23509 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, client-instance restarting
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_the rest_" ? Rest of the line ? Otherwise, there needs to be a big intelligence addition to the regex.

Comment: @sln, I only matched the ` Connection reset, restarting` but I want  to match the others too like the "TLS error" or "Verify Error"  for all the IPs that are shown here. So it gives the matches in a new line.

Comment: `(\d{3}\.\d{2, 3}\.\d{2, 3}\.\d{2, 3}\:\d{4, 6})` should capture the IP and ports. You'll need a bit more to capture the rest. If you're wanting to capture every line you can just do this `(\d{3}\.\d{2, 3}\.\d{2, 3}\.\d{2, 3}\:\d{4, 6}.*$)`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I do understand _the rest of the line_.

Comment: If you're just wanting to strip off the initial part you can do this too. `.*ovpn-openvpn_.{3}\[\d{3}\]\:\s(.*)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` to separate different options that you would like to capture. Since most of the options start with IP address, you could share your IP-matching regex among all of them.

Here is a regex with some "formatting" for easier understanding of what is going on; remove unnecessary spaces and end-of-line markers in the real regex:

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+ 
    (?:
        Connection reset, restarting
    |   TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
    |   Fatal TLS Error
    |   VERIFY ERROR
    |   Bad encapsulated packet length
    )
|   TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET]\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/wvC4nm/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem may be divided into 2 parts:

1. What regex is used to represent the patterns, and
2. How to capture the IP address the OP is interested in.

**Represent the patterns with the "or" and "group" operators**

I think the multiple possibilities that follow the IP address may be handled by using the `|` operator and the `(` `)` grouping operator:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5} (Connection reset|TLS Error|Fatal TLS Error|VERIFY ERROR|Bad encapsulated packet length)
```

The more complicated case is the last possibility that the IP address appears the last, such as in the message

> Jun 19 16:59:10 Server ovpn-openvpn_udp[811]: TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]185.200.118.41:40431

I think a quick and dirty solution might be to wrap this case with a pair of `()`and the other cases with another pair of `()` and then `|` them together:

```
((TLS Error.+\[AF_INET\])(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5}))|(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5} (Connection reset|TLS Error|Fatal TLS Error|VERIFY ERROR|Bad encapsulated packet length))
```

With this regex, a user will be able to obtain the lines that contain the interesting patterns. This pattern includes both the IP address and the error info, and now with 1 further step, the user can extract the parts of interest (in this case, IP address and port number) ---

**Return only the matched parts**

To tell a regex that some part is not part of the match result (and are used only as delimiters, for example), you can declare them as "lookaheads" (  `(?=blah blah)` ). The following shows how a one-liner with grep extracts the intruders:

```
$ grep -P "((?=TLS Error.+\[AF_INET\])(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5}))|((\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5}) (?=Connection reset|TLS Error|Fatal TLS Error|VERIFY ERROR|Bad encapsulated packet length))" -o temp.txt

67.52.172.103:63975
154.16.133.10:13456
154.16.133.10:13769
184.105.139.70:50240
223.146.71.5:59970
223.146.71.5:60145
112.113.195.89:3079
112.113.195.89:3079
213.202.230.144:2616
213.202.230.144:2616
178.73.215.171:23509
```

The `-o` tells grep to return only the matched parts; `-P` tells grep to use PCRE regex rather than POSIX regex.

Hope this may be useful!